# Can't create SessionFactory in Hibernate Tools Console

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I want to use hibernate console in my JPA project. I'm using Hibernate. When I try to create a Session Factory the following error appears in the Error Log:

[image: Error Log from Hibernate Tools]

If I double click the message a dialog appears with more detailed information:

Message:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: <no message>
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1378)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$5.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
```

How can I solve this? I just wanted to test my JPQL/HQL queries. So any other solution that offers this is good to me.

Thank you.

Comment: show your hibernate-cfg.xml file which contains mapping for your hibernate entity.

Comment: @SardarWaqasAhmed I'm not using hibernate xml files. I use JPA annotations and Hibernate Entity Manager. Anyway, in the Hibernate view my mappings show up correctly. All my Entities are listed.